# Rubygems 2.0.14 is not threadsafe bunder install message when using - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5.1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundler

When running the bundle install I get the following message:

```
Rubygems 2.0.14 is not threadsafe, so your gems will be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
```

Which is strange because in my RubyGems Environment it says my RubyGems Version is: 2.4.5.1 (see below)

```
~/w/Rafftopia ❯❯❯ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.5 (2016-04-26 patchlevel 319) [x86_64-darwin14]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/phillipjones/.gem/ruby/2.2.5
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/phillipjones/.rubies/ruby-2.2.5/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/phillipjones/.gem/ruby/2.2.5/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/phillipjones/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/phillipjones/.rubies/ruby-2.2.5/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I posted another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902348/bundle-install-using-old-rubygems-version). Did you figure this out? If not, hopefully someone can answer one of us

Comment: I don't know what my exact problem was but when I removed my `Gemfile.lock` I didn't have any issues anymore. I also switched to RVM instead of rbenv...not sure if that had anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

run `sudo gem update --system`

reference: http://blog.rubygems.org/2017/03/16/2.6.11-released.html