# bundle install using old rubygems version

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm having what appears to be the exact same problem seen in a [1-month old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279896/rubygems-2-0-14-is-not-threadsafe-bunder-install-message-when-using-rubygems-v) that no one has touched. I installed rbenv using homebrew, installed ruby 2.3.1 using `rbenv install 2.3.1`, installed jekyll and bundler using `gem install jekyll` and `gem install bundler`, then within a jekyll project, I typed `bundle install`. I got the error `Rubygems 2.0.14.1 is not threadsafe, so your gems will be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.` When I run `gem env`, I see this:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.1 (2016-04-26 patchlevel 112) [x86_64-darwin15]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/lindsb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/lindsb/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/lindsb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/lindsb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/lindsb/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/lindsb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-15
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/lindsb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
     - /Users/lindsb/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/lindsb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/libexec
     - /Users/lindsb/.local/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /Users/lindsb/.rbenv/shims
     - /Users/lindsb/.local/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /opt/X11/bin
     - /Library/TeX/texbin
```

I don't understand why bundler complains about Rubygems being below 2.1.0 when my Rubygems version is 2.6.6.
There is a `Gemfile` and a `Gemfile.lock` in the project directory. `Gemfile` looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'                                                      

# jekyll                                                                           
gem "jekyll", "3.1.1"                                                              
gem "redcarpet"                                                                    

# compiling less                                                                   
gem 'therubyracer'                                                                 
gem 'less'                                                                         

# minifying                                                                        
gem 'jekyll-press'                                                                 

# octokit                                                                          
gem 'octokit'                                                                      
gem 'netrc'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what the issue was, but when I removed `Gemfile.lock` and reran `bundle install` everything worked fine. There were probably just some bad constraints or something in `Gemfile.lock`.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I am learing Rails and encountered the same issue and I don't know what the root cause it is. But when I try reinstall bundler again

```
gem install bundler
```

and then run

```
bundle install
```

everything goes fine now.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that didn't change anything for me when I just tried it.

Comment: This worked for me on a MacBook Pro, but I needed to "sudo" as the install seems to be in a protected space.